# UPDATE Column data with the closest value from another table on oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this table "table_1"

```
Column
1039
3900
2345
```

And Table_2

```
Column
1038
1090
3903
4502
2340
2900
4500
```

i need to update the table_1 with the most closest value from table 2 to be like this :

```
1039 => 1038
3900 => 3903
```

and so on .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross Join the tables, find the column in Table2 with the least difference.
Use the `FIRST` aggregate function to get this column.

```
SELECT a.col
    ,MIN(b.col) KEEP (
        DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY (ABS(a.col - b.col))
        ) as col2
FROM Table1 a
CROSS JOIN Table2 b
GROUP BY a.col;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a69c/8)

To update the table, use a correlated update from the above select.

```
update table1 o set col = ( SELECT 
    MIN(b.col) KEEP (
        DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY (ABS(a.col - b.col))
        ) as col2
FROM Table1 a
CROSS JOIN Table2 b
Where a.col = o.col
GROUP BY a.col );
```